# Authorize.NET creating a subscription from authorized CC charge

Tags: subscription, authorize.net

We are using `AuthOnlyTransaction`, and later `PriorAuthCaptureTransaction` transaction types to authorize and capture order charges.

We would like to add a subscription option, which would follow the same scenario - user funds are first authorized, then captured.

There is currently a way to `Create ARB Subscription from Transaction` in the Sanbox GUI, Sandbox > Unsettled Transactions > Pick on auth-only transaction > Click "Create ARB Subscription from Transaction":

[image]

How can we create an ARB Subscription for an authorized charge from the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a customer profile and payment profile using the CIM API when you first get your authorization. Then once you are ready to create the subscription you can create it using those profile IDs.

Here is sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
    <merchantAuthentication>
        <name>API_USERNAME</name>
        <transactionKey>API_TRANSACTION_KEY</transactionKey>
    </merchantAuthentication>
    <refId>Sample</refId>
    <subscription>
        <name>Sample subscription</name>
        <paymentSchedule>
            <interval>
                <length>1</length>
                <unit>months</unit>
            </interval>
            <startDate>2020-08-30</startDate>
            <totalOccurrences>12</totalOccurrences>
            <trialOccurrences>1</trialOccurrences>
        </paymentSchedule>
        <amount>10.00</amount>
        <trialAmount>0.00</trialAmount>
        <profile>
            <customerProfileId>12345678</customerProfileId>
            <customerPaymentProfileId>987654342</customerPaymentProfileId>
        </profile>
    </subscription>
</ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest>
```

Comment: yes, we are already doing that in our app. I am trying to find out if there is a way to  do `ARBCreateSubscriptionRequest` from a `AuthOnlyTransaction` like we see in the GUI.

Comment: There is not a way to do that and I do not believe they have any plans to do so.